# ng2-dragula - Use the copy function only for a specific target?

Tags: angular, dragula, ng2-dragula, angular-dragula

How do I copy some thing instead of moving it only when dragging it to a specific target.

I have 4 containers, and I want to make the value get copied to a container when something is dragged to it. For all the other containers I just want the value to get moved from source to target (as is the default behaviour).

The `copy` function in the ng2-dragula docs has only the `element` and `source` as arguments, but no target.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create `dragover` event and change copy option function run time.

HTML

```
<div (dragover)="changeMethod()"></div>
```

TS

```
changeMethod(){
  // here write logic for change option for target.
  this.copyOption = false;
}
```

i hope this will helps.